# JavaScript - Порядковый номер элемента

Tags: javascript

Имеется div блок с несколькими раскрывающимися списками

```
<div id="block">
    <select class="abl" onchange="Group(this)">
        ...
    </select>
    <select class="abl" onchange="Group(this)">
        ...
    </select>
</div>
```

При выборе чего-либо в раскрывающемся списке требуется узнать в каком именно списке произошло действие (порядковый номер внутри блока, !! не какой option выбран, а в каком списке произошло действие !!). Для этого передается параметр onchange через который вызывается функция Group

```
function Group(elm) {
    console.log( "Index: " + $('#block').index(elm.target));
}
```

Почему то постоянно выводится Index: 0, даже если списков несколько, подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function Group(elm) {
    console.log( "Index: " + $('select').index(elm));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="block">
    <select class="abl" onchange="Group(this)">
        <option>Пункт 1</option>
        <option>Пункт 2</option>
    </select>
    <select class="abl" onchange="Group(this)">
        <option>Пункт 1</option>
        <option>Пункт 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
```